# How to jump from one json file to another using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, json

I have to show 10 data at a time from first.json file and next 10 data after clicking to the load more button.

if the data from first.json file have finished then it load data from second.json file and dynamically add them to the table, 10 at a time.

link to
[first json file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujum46elead7hm6/first.json?dl=0),
[second json file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5o708rnged66bf/second.json?dl=0)

----------my  file looks like

```js
$(function(){
 
 var getTblId = document.getElementById("article-tble");
 
 var load = function(){
 $.getJSON( "articles.json", function(data) {
  $.getJSON( "more-articles.json", function(data2){
  
  var text="";
  var j = total_len = $("tbody tr").length; 
  
  total_len+=10;
      $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
   if(i>=j && i<total_len){
   console.log("master data i->"+i+" j->"+j+" total_len->"+total_len)
   text += "<tr>";
    text += "<td class='title'>"+"<img src ='"+val.image+"' alt=''>"+ "<a href='"+val.url+"'>" +val.title+"</a>" +"</td>";
    text += "<td class='author'>" + val.profile.first_name + val.profile.last_name + "</td>";
    text += "<td class='words'>" + val.words + "</td>";
    text += "<td class='submitted'>" + val.publish_at + "</td>";
    text += "</tr>" ;
   }
   
      });
   $("#article-tble table tbody").append(text);

   
   

   
    }); 
 });
 }

$('#button_load a').click(function() {
load()
});
load()
});
```

```html
<div id="article-tble">
<table>
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>Unpublished Articles</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Words</th>
<th>Submitted</th>
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="button_load"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Load More Content</a></div>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you please share that also?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, try this approach:
EDIT2, fixed some scopes in own answer.

```
$(function() {

var getTblId = document.getElementById("article-tble");

var load = function (url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        var text = "";

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            text += "<tr>";
            text += "<td class='title'>" + "<img src ='" + val.image + "' alt=''>" + "<a href='" + val.url + "'>" + val.title + "</a>" + "</td>";
            text += "<td class='author'>" + val.profile.first_name + val.profile.last_name + "</td>";
            text += "<td class='words'>" + val.words + "</td>";
            text += "<td class='submitted'>" + val.publish_at + "</td>";
            text += "</tr>";
        });

        $("#article-tble table tbody").append(text);


    });
}

$('#button_load a').click(function () {
    load("more-articles.json");
});
load("articles.json");
}
```

Basically what I changed is added a param to the load function. So first time you are loading data with url `articles.json`, an then when clicking button, load `more-articles.json`

Comment: I maksim thanks for giving answer, I have done edit to the question pls check it again I want 10 data at a time